# counter that counts pages when its scroll down

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginner in flutter and programming,  want To set counter that count images number when it scroll down and also tell remaining pages instead of hardcoded text('1/6'). here it's code

```
int counter=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Center(
          child: Text('Surah Yaseen' '  (1/6) ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        allowImplicitScrolling: true,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/1.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/2.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/3.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/4.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/5.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/6.jpg'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  final controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  final _currentPageNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Center(
          child: Text('Surah Yaseen' '  (${_currentPageNotifier.value}/6) ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        allowImplicitScrolling: true,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPageNotifier.value = index+1;
          });
        },
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/1.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/2.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/3.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/4.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/5.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/6.jpg'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```